# Customize background of IDA "Mark as decompiled" functions

Tags: background, customization, ida

I seem to cannot find how to change the background colour of IDA pro function when it is marked as decompiled.

The current colour makes it an absolute pain to the eyes to read.
[image]

Any advice is absolutely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the decompiled function background colour:

- Go to **Edit -> Plugins -> Hex-Rays Decompiler**
- Select **Options**
- Select **Marked Function Colour** and choose a colour